# javascript sorting decimal numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, sorting

Ok I have a section of code that sorts the names it is given alphabetically.

However the code doesnt handle decimals the way I would want.

It orders the name in the following manner (Obv I would rather it incremented numerically):

It would order it:

- APPLE - 1.0051
- APPLE - 1.1071
- APPLE - 11.1592
- APPLE - 12.0692
- APPLE - 12.1717
- APPLE - 2.0186   << this should be after "APPLE - 1.1071" obviously
- APPLE - 21.1407
- APPLE - 22.089
- APPLE - 23.069
- BANANA - 1.0051
- BANANA - 1.1071
- BANANA - 11.1592
- BANANA - 12.0692
- BANANA - 12.1717
- BANANA - 2.0186   << this should be after "BANANA - 1.1071" obviously
- BANANA - 21.1407
- BANANA - 22.089
- BANANA - 23.069

Here is the code I am using. I do not fully understand the code as it was a snippet I have been using.

```
function(a, b){
         var nameA=a.myname.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.myname.toLowerCase()
         if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
          return -1 
         if (nameA > nameB)
          return 1
         return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
    }
```

Regards,
Jonny

Comment: Right now you are sorting by text strings (ascii sort).  You could put leading zeroes on the numbers: 01.0001, or you'll have to split the numbers out of the string, convert them and then sort by two fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/wphH8/)  and here is the source + small explanation:

```
function fruit_sort(a, b) {
    var parts = {
        a: a.split('-'),
        b: b.split('-')
    };
    if (parts.a[0] == parts.b[0]) // strings are the same
        return parseFloat(parts.a[1]) - parseFloat(parts.b[1]); // sort by number
    return parts.a[0] > parts.b[0] ? 1 : -1; // sort by string
}
var arr = ["APPLE - 1.0051",
    "APPLE - 1.1071",
    "APPLE - 11.1592",
    "APPLE - 12.0692",
    "BANANA - 1.0051",
    "BANANA - 1.1071",
    "BANANA - 11.1592",
    "BANANA - 12.0692",
    "BANANA - 12.1717",
    "APPLE - 12.1717",
    "APPLE - 2.0186",
    "APPLE - 21.1407",
    "BANANA - 23.069",
    "APPLE - 22.089",
    "APPLE - 23.069",
    "BANANA - 2.0186",
    "BANANA - 21.1407",
    "BANANA - 22.089"];
arr.sort(fruit_sort);
console.log(arr);
// outputs
[
    "APPLE - 1.0051",
    "APPLE - 1.1071",
    "APPLE - 2.0186",
    "APPLE - 11.1592",
    "APPLE - 12.0692",
    "APPLE - 12.1717",
    "APPLE - 21.1407",
    "APPLE - 22.089",
    "APPLE - 23.069",
    "BANANA - 1.0051",
    "BANANA - 1.1071",
    "BANANA - 2.0186",
    "BANANA - 11.1592",
    "BANANA - 12.0692",
    "BANANA - 12.1717",
    "BANANA - 21.1407",
    "BANANA - 22.089",
    "BANANA - 23.069"
]
```

First the function splits the terms up into their text and numerical parts - if the text is even it only sorts on the parseFloat value of the numerical value - otherwise it sorts first by the string value.

Comment: I got this to work by using changing it slightly to the following: `code`function(a, b) {
    var parts = {
        a: a.myname.split(' - '),
        b: b.myname.split(' - ')
    };
    if (parts.a[0] == parts.b[0]) // strings are the same
        return parseFloat(parts.a[1]) - parseFloat(parts.b[1]); // sort by number
    return parts.a[0] > parts.b[0] ? 1 : -1; // sort by string
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
function (x, y) {
    x=x.myname;
    y=y.myname;

    var nameA = x.toLowerCase().split("-")[0],
        nameB = y.toLowerCase().split("-")[0]
    if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
    return -1
    if (nameA > nameB) return 1
    var floatExtract = /(([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?/;
    if (floatExtract.test(x) && floatExtract.test(y)) {
        x = x.match(floatExtract)[1];
        y = y.match(floatExtract)[1];
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(x)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(y))) {
            x = parseInt(x);
            y = parseInt(y);
        }
        return ((x > y) ? 1 : ((x < y) ? -1 : 0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It splits your string and does a simple comparison with the first portion [before the hyphen], then searches for a float inside of your string and does another sort on the list against that...

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YDf4Y/6/show) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/YDf4Y/6/)

Comment: This only appears to sort by the numerical section :S

Comment: Updated answer, do you need *.myname as the string to be sorted?

Comment: ok I have tried this code and it still sorts it the same way. The *.myname is the string to be sorted and is in the format of "Apple - 1.0051" etc ok I get and error "match(...).1 is null or not an object

Comment: Updated answer again to include match detection.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Steve Wellens suggested in his comment, I modified your existing snippet to compare the text parts first, then in the event of a tie compare the numeric portions of the string, by converting them to `float`s.   If you would like to sort **solely** by the numeric portion of the string then @extramaster 's answer should serve you well.

```
function(a, b){
        var parts, textPartA, textPartB, numericPartA, numericPartB;

        parts = a.split('-');
        textPartA = parts[0];
        numericPartA = parseFloat(parts[1]);

        parts = b.split('-');
        textPartB = parts[0];
        numericPartB = parseFloat(parts[1]);

        //sort by text first
        if(textPartA < textPartB) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(textPartA > textPartB) {
            return 1;
        }

        //text parts are equal, now sort by the numeric parts
        if(numericPartA < numericPartB){
            return -1;
        }
        if(numericPartA > numericPartB){
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

@Jonny: [A quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/H2w9B/1/)

Comment: I cannot seem to get this code to work :S Could you provide a demo? Thank you for your assistance so far.

Comment: Added an example. Can you provide me with some more information, as to why you "cannot seem to get this code to work."  Are you getting errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: I get an error saying object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now. The function variables `a` and `b` aren't strings but objects.  The split part should've been written as: `a.myname.split('-')` and not `a.split('-')`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar solution on another page:
[Javascript not sorting DECIMAL numbers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683662/javascript-not-sorting-decimal-numbers-correctly)

The idea is to sort by the string first then the number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I used rlemon's code sample and edited it to the following:

```
function(a, b) {
var parts = {
    a: a.myname.split(' - '),
    b: b.myname.split(' - ')
};
if (parts.a[0] == parts.b[0]) // strings are the same
    return parseFloat(parts.a[1]) - parseFloat(parts.b[1]); // sort by number
return parts.a[0] > parts.b[0] ? 1 : -1; // sort by string
```

}